# Redux createAsyncThunk vs useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm familiar with react hooks, and i find it really easy to work with useEffect, thunk is very difficult to deal with, can i just use useEffect & axios and just dispatch the result to the store without using createAsyncThunk? is there any major performance benefit to use it over useEffect?

createAsyncThunk:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { userAPI } from './userAPI'

// First, create the thunk
const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/fetchByIdStatus',
  async (userId, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await userAPI.fetchById(userId)
    return response.data
  }
)

// Then, handle actions in your reducers:
const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState: { entities: [], loading: 'idle' },
  reducers: {
    // standard reducer logic, with auto-generated action types per reducer
  },
  extraReducers: {
    // Add reducers for additional action types here, and handle loading state as needed
    [fetchUserById.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
      // Add user to the state array
      state.entities.push(action.payload)
    }
  }
})

// Later, dispatch the thunk as needed in the app
dispatch(fetchUserById(123))
```

useEffect:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { userAPI } from './userAPI'
import axios from 'axios';
 
function App() {  
const dispatch = useDispatch()
useEffect(() => {
axios
  .get(userAPI)
  .then(response => dispatch({type:'fetchUsers',payload:response.data}));
    }, []);
```

Comment: The question you want to ask yourself is "which part of my app do I want responsible for handling async API calls?" and then use the tools at that level to handle that. If you believe your visual component should handle that, then use `useEffect`; if you think your redux state should, then use the `createAsyncThunk` tool. Separation of responsibilities is very helpful in creating clear boundaries for what a thing should do, and makes for much easier testing and hunting down bugs if they occur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two setups are essentially similar.  You can do the same thing with both approaches.

With the codes exactly as you have them written here, there is a major advantage to the `createAsyncThunk` approach because it will `catch` any errors that occur in the API call.  It will respond to those errors by dispatching a `fetchUserById.rejected` action instead of a `fetchUserById.fulfilled` action.  Your reducer doesn't responded to the `rejected` case which is fine.  The error is still caught.  With your `useEffect` you run the risk of "uncaught error in Promise" errors.

Now of course you can `catch` the errors on your own. You can also `dispatch` a `pending` action at the start of the effect.  But once you start doing that, the `createAsyncThunk` might feel a lot easier by comparison since it automatically dispatches `pending`, `fulfilled`, and `rejected` actions.

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({ type: "fetchUsers/pending" });
  axios
    .get(userAPI)
    .then((response) =>
      dispatch({ type: "fetchUsers", payload: response.data })
    )
    .catch((error) =>
      dispatch({ type: "fetchUsers/rejected", payload: error.message })
    );
}, []);
```

Comment: Just a tiny tip: with `useEffect` you have no problem with hooks, in `createAsyncThunk`, it's not that easy (for example: fetching a JWT Token from an external IDP like Auth0 is not possible in extrareducer, you have to provide it somehow there, but in `useEffect` you can do it directly)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning `response.data` just return the api call without the await. That way you have the fulfilled, rejected statuses.

As for your question is a matter of what do you need this data for? Just in this component or more than 1 component? You can use the context api as well for higher sharing of data among components, but to be honest if you are a beginner with react I would understand hooks and react well before you introduce redux. Usually production apps, not to say 100% but the majority, use some kind of state management with async. Also you can look into react-query as another option on how to handle async stuff.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the question.  The first example will dispatch `pending`, `fulfilled`, and `rejected` actions automatically because that's what [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) does. They are using Redux and dispatching actions in both examples.  It's just a question of whether the `async` logic is handled in the component or with `redux-thunk` middleware.

Answer (score 1):

Linda Paiste is correct.
Just to extend the answer to your question a bit further, the other very popular option is [TanStack Query (React Query)](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/overview). It gives you what you are asking for:

```
const { isLoading, error, data } = useQuery(['repoData'], () =>
    fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/tannerlinsley/react-query').then(res =>
      res.json()
    )
  )
```

1. It nicely takes care of the caching in `repoData` similar to RTKQ.
2. It returns the response status `isLoading, error, data` back to you, again just like RTKQ.
3. You can use RESTful `axios` or `fetch` or any non-RESTful request freely.
4. *IMO* it is more compact, easier shorter learning curve, without mouthful of weird words for beginners like slice reducer extra redeucer thunk...etc